# Calling a WPF Application and modify exposed properties?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, shell, .net-4.0

I have a WPF Keyboard Application, it is developed in such a way that an application could call it and modify its properties to adapt the Keyboard to do what it needs to. Right now I have a file *.Keys.Set which tells the application (on open) to style itself according to that new style. I know this file could be passed as a command line argument into the application.

That would not be a problem. My concern is, is there a way via a managed environment to change the properties of the executable as long as they are exposed properly, an example:

```
'Creates a new instance of the Keyboard Application
Dim e_key as new WpfApplication("C:\egt\components\keyboard.exe")
'Sets the style path
e_key.SetStylePath("c:\users\joe\apps\me\default.keys.set")
e_key.Refresh()    'Applies the style
e_key.HideMenu()   'Hides the menu
e_key.ShowDeck("PIN") 'Shows the custom "deck" of keyboard keys the developer 
    'Created in the style application.

''work with events and response

'Clear the instance from memory
e_key.close
e_key.dispose
e_key = nothing
```

This would allow my application to become easily accessible to other Touch Screen Application Developers, allowing them to use my keyboard and keep the functionality they need. It seems like it might be possible because (name of executable).application shows all the exposed functions, properties, and values. I just have never done this before. Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you want this to be a separate executable, and not just a class library that you can create an instance of and use like any other control?

Comment: You might want to decide on one or the other of "application" or "appliaction" for consistency's sake. ;-)

Comment: I rewrote the project as a DLL Reference, which is good now its a importable object to other projects. How should I keep this DLL as a reference to it in a file path, this way anyone using it will always get the system most up to date DLL possible? I would hate to have to Store it in the GAC, because then one can not upgrade the reference, instead I leave the old and would have to put a new reference out. Defeating the purpose of upgrading the DLL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Abe Heidebrecht , the best way is to create a class library and exposing the functions in a class.